# Food which is not cooked yet

Tags: meaning, word-choice

How do I say a vegetable or some meat is not cooked yet?

Is it **raw** or **fresh**?

Because uncooked meat/vegetable may be rotten. And they may not be fresh.

---

> ... add spices, salt, water with vegetables/meat and keep them **on stove** (with flame) for an hour

Is this **boil** or **cook**?

It can't be *cook*, because I am not stirring, or applying any special procedure to the food.

Comment: Have you looked up these words in a dictionary? Something which is raw is not necessarily fresh, and something fresh is not necessarily raw (e.g. freshly-baked bread). Cooking is a process which could involve boiling, frying, grilling, baking etc.

Comment: It's "keep them on the stove for an hour and then realize you never turned the heat on."  A recipe that involves placing an item  "on the stove" should include instruction for the level of heat to be applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- It's 'uncooked' for something that is not cooked yet. Translates to:

> not cooked; raw:

Ref: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/uncooked

- Simmer makes more sense instead of cook or boil in this case

Comment: Consider also "simmer", a little gentler than boiling

Comment: _Boil_ does not make sense in this case, no. Boiling is done at a temperature where a liquid “bubbles and turns to vapour” (ODO). You don’t boil food for an entire hour—it would likely evaporate, or at least be ruined. You might bring it to a boil and then turn down the heat and let it simmer it for an hour.

Comment: I agree -Simmer makes more sense. Updating the answer

Comment: *Simmering, boiling, baking, roasting, frying, poaching, broiling,* and so forth are all different forms of *cooking*. It's better to use a specific verb in recipes, but saying *cooking* is still correct.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Malvolio up to a point regarding the usage of *uncooked* vs. *raw*.   But *raw* can also be used to refer to food which is intended to be cooked.

*Fresh* can refer to food which is cooked as well as that which is uncooked. Food ceases to be *fresh* when its flavour, texture, appearance or edibility deteriorate.

Answer (score 0):

"Uncooked" and "undercooked" imply that the food ought to be cooked ("uncooked chicken").

"Raw" implies a deliberate simplicity in preparation.  It hasn't been cooked, heavily spiced, or aged.

"Fresh" means that the food is not only uncooked but literally fresh: newly arrived from its source.